# Glide, override size of placeholder?

Tags: android, android-glide

I want to override the size of the placeholder and error drawables in Glide. I tried

```
    Glide.with(fragment)
            .load(url)
            .apply(new RequestOptions()
                  .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_icon)
                  .error(R.drawable.loading_error)
                  .override(200))
```

and

```
    Glide.with(fragment)
            .load(url)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_icon)
            .error(R.drawable.loading_error)
            .apply(new RequestOptions().override(200))
```

and none of these two solutions work.
While the image is being downloaded, I can clearly see the placeholder image's displayed size is not 200 pixels, as I expect it to be. `override()` seems to work with `into()`, but not with `placeholder()` or `error()`.

I am using Glide 4.13.2 with OkHttp backend:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.2'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.13.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try add the following line into your Glide configurations, like they mention in this issue https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/542:

```
.dontAnimate()
```

So it will become something like this:

```
  Glide.with(context)
            .load(imageUrl)
            .placeholder(placeholderImage)
            .override(100, 100)
            .dontAnimate()
            .into(imageView);
```